# Cannot convert "String" to "int" when trying to get value by column name

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to populate a text box with miles.  I have a table which stores Routes and Miles where i have a dropdown list populated with these Routes.  When i try to get the miles read into the text box I am getting compile time error "Cannot convert 'string' to 'int'" in following code (for both `GetInt32` and `GetDecimal`).

```
private void location_comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = "****ConnectionString*****";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Location_Table WHERE Route = '" +
        location_comboBox.Text + "';"; // simplified, actual code uses parametrized query
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
         String Miles = myReader.GetInt32("Miles").ToString();
         mileage_textbox.Text = Miles;
    }
}
```

Line `String Miles = myReader.GetInt32("Miles").ToString();` gives error

> Cannot convert "string" to "int"

which makes sense as `SqlDataReader.GetInt32` expects some sort of index ("The zero-based column ordinal."), but I'd like to use column names

Column types in DB:

- Miles -  Decimal(3,1)
- Route - varchar(50)
- id - nchar(10) (not used in sample)

Comment: I tried mileage_textbox.Text = myReader.GetString("Miles"); but io still get the same error as before :( .  I have also got rid of the .ToString()

Comment: Additionally, you should never, ever glue data into strings to make SQL.  It is very prone to error, outdated and even dangerous.  Use SQL Parameters always

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow I think current version of post should get OP this hint already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Miles = myReader.GetDecimal(myReader.GetOrdinal("Miles")).ToString();

Comment: Good catch I'll get that changed,

Comment: I have tried "Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["Miles"]);"   but it displays        cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'.   for the 2nd one is there an error where the ])) is at the end.  tried adding a bracket in and a "[" infront of miles but no luck @Ryan.  Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Johnathan I fixed the bottom one. Just removed the [

Comment: I stil get the error " cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'. " :'(   it also says  Exceptions: InvalidCast Exception.

Comment: did you add .ToString() to the end?

Comment: Re-Run the Program and used " myReader.GetDecimal(myReader.GetOrdinal("Miles")).ToString(); " this has solved my query.  Thank you @Ryan